# issue with math.log

Tags: python, math

I've been trying to code this program with my Python editor using the math library. Essentially I'm trying to have a user input any positive number, and then given their positive number show an output of the first power of  2^n which is equal to or greater than their input.
 For example my code works when the user inputs 256, the output becomes

> "256.0 is the first power greater than or equal to 256".

However when the user input's the number such as 248, the out becomes

> " 495.99 is the first power greater than or equal to 248".

Which is what I don't want, I need the first power equal to greater than 248 to show, thus the correct output would have been

> "256 is the first power greater than or equal to 248".

I have written the code that I have below and open to any suggestions that can improve the code.

```
import math
number= int(input("Enter any positive integer value greater : "))
assert number >=2, "Number must be greater than or equal to 2"
x=math.log2(number)
y=math.pow(2,x)
print(x)
print(y)

if y == number:
    print(y, "is the first power greater than or equal to", number)
elif number != y:
    z=x+1
    k=math.floor(z)
    a=math.pow(2,k)  
    print(a, "is the first power greater than or equal to", number)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to round z down to an integer number. Use math.floor() for that.

Comment: Ok so that does improve that code, like for example if I enter 248, it will show 256 is greater than or equal to 248, however if I enter a number such as 120, the code does not output anything- when it should infact say 128 is the first power greater than or equal to 120.

Comment: I think you also need to use it in your math.pow call: `y = math.pow(2, math.floor(x))`

Comment: Got it to work, basically, Instead of y > number or y<number just put in y!=number: and the code works for any input value now

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudocode to get you started:

```
//n = user input
//int power = 0;
//while(2^power < n){power++}
//output "power" variable to system.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're taking 2 to the power of a non integer number, because you're doing 2^(x+1) and x is not an integer. You need to just round x up to the nearest integer instead of adding 1, so do

> z = math.ceil(x)

Or something like that.